# Count and Proportion of Cells Adjacent to Cells of the Same Value in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have 3 columns, and I am trying to find the number of cells that contain a certain value and are adjacent/touching cells that have the same value. I am having trouble writing the formula in excel to perform this task for just one value.

As you can see in the table I only want to count the number of "Green" cells that are adjacent to other "Green" cells ( I did it by hand in the image for explanation purposes)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, replace the first `0` in "Adjacent" column and drag down:

`=IF(AND(C2="Green",OR(C1="Green",C3="Green")),1,"")`